# Bind event to <img /> or <a />?

Tags: html, dom-events

**Problem:**
I'm not sure whether it is technically better to bind generic events to inner or outer tags.
Also concerns deeper nested tags.

**Aspects:**
Does either use less CPU?
Does either have side effects?
Does either trigger more or less delayed?
Inheritance?
`this`?

**What I/we already found out:**

- `onclick` on `<a />` does trigger right before following the link
- `onload` does only get triggered by a few tags which really load and display (works on `<img />`, not on `<a />`)

Variant example A:

```
<a href="#" onclick="function();">
  <img src="picture.jpg" />
</a>
```

Variant example B:

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="picture.jpg" onclick="function();" />
</a>
```

---

The following is rather unrelated but an explanation has been demanded in the comments:

> "whats the point of having an `<a>` tag surrounding the image if
>   you are binding the onclick to the `<img>` tag?" - @Trug

The point is SEO friendly links with the ability to sidechain effects like an exit modal with a warning, an exit transition animation, an analytics event, or just as a kind of destructor.

Example:

```
<a href="http://seo.friendly.url/deeplink.htm" 
   onclick="triggerSpecialAnalyticsForExample(); triggerExitModal();">link</a>
```

Comment: Please tell my why you think this is a bad question. Thanks!

Comment: whats the point of having an `<a>` tag surrounding the image if you are binding the onclick to the `<img>` tag?

Comment: If I knew the advantages, I wouldn't ask? @Trug it's just an example, substitute by any event..... you people downvote before you even understood the question.

Comment: + As you pro's know, onclick gets triggered before a real click on the link, there are enough use-cases.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I didn't down vote... I was just asking you a question

Comment: I could imagine the downvoters are irritated that you did not elaborate on the actual idea behind your code

Comment: I have 2 variants of code and I simply ask wether one of them is better, it doesn't matter which context this code is in or which idea is behind it because all this is about is the event bound to the element.

Comment: It makes ALL the difference, especially as it turns out one of your examples are not supported at all. It saves us time and gives you a much better answer if we know what you are trying to do. With 12K rep I am surprised you are annoyed that some of us question the background of your question before attempting to answer it.
Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: It's such a simple question, there is no context or idea, or thing I want to achieve. It's a general question. General questions without context are pretty legit.  If you need a context, well....
The point that people upvote Trug's question proves that some people without web-knowledge are judging my question or even downvote it.

Comment: I cannot let this go uncommented. Your question seems simple to you but without knowing what you are trying to solve, I have MANY suggestions.
* if the onload is important, then example A will not work. * if you want to use onclick of a link for the single side effect of a pointer, then you EITHER need to return false from the onclick OR - cleaner - remove the link completely, use onclick of the image and style it with a pointer. * That might however give issues with screen readers. I only just got started. Can you see why your question might not be perceived as simple?

Comment: @mplungjan I understand that there should be 1 question and 1 answer (per thread) but what's wrong with an answer covering more than 1 aspect? Almost every question on SO requires an answer covering more than a single aspect?!

Comment: I have not said anything about a question comparing solutions. I just wanted to know what the actual problem to solve is. In this case I am still not sure of whether you are asking about event bubbling or multiple event handlers on one object or what.

Comment: @mplungjan My problem: I do need to know wether there is a difference between binding events to the inner tag (<img />) or the outer tag (<a />). I have added those two variants to the question as a demonstration.

Comment: I understand - the answer is: That depends. As said: You cannot use onload on the link and you will trigger two events if you add onclick to the image, one javascript and the other will follow the # and in some browsers partially unload the page (stop animations typically) when bubbling up to the `<A>`. Hence the question we asked was - what is important to you.

Comment: @mplungjan When I do not know all these details/aspects, how should I tell you which detail/aspect is important to me, seriously? All details/aspects are important to me. I don't get why you have a problem with a question that requires more than a single aspect to be covered in the answer.

Comment: You misunderstand. I ha no problem with more than one aspect. Never mind

Comment: @mplungjan do you think it's ok to google all SO answers which start with "That depends:" in the first paragraph and downvote all of them?

Comment: @mplungjan I didn't mean any offense to you personally. I really don't get the problem.

Comment: Because your question sounded like an X/y problem as I was not the only one to mention

Comment: @mplungjan def not a xy-question

Answer (score 2):

Simple - variant B every day of the week and 4 times on the 29th of Feb. Why? Simple - the anchor element doesn't support the load event, thus waiting for it will take a *very* long time.

Using `.addEventListener` would be an even better method of attaching the handler to the element for all kinds of reasons.

Comment: May I ask was it hard for you to understand the question? Because your answer is perfect "<a /> does not trigger onload".

Comment: You said in your comment above that "it's just an example, substitute by any event", so that doesn't make sense. Is `onload` relevant to your question or isn't it?

Comment: @DanFromGermany - Of course. Nope - what you were trying to find out seemed perfectly straight-forward. It's a somewhat odd question (the original one) and I can imagine that someone's pinged it because you could have investigated both methods on your own in a minute or two and discovered yourself that one way wont work - that would qualify it for the "does not show any research effort" down-vote suggestion. Members here often tend to dislike theoretical questions too, preferring a very concrete, tangible one. Without giving a reason for wondering, it may seem a little too abstract for some.

Comment: @j08691 - I suspect not, though can't quite tell. I think I'm detecting a slight odour of an X/Y here.

Comment: What would be the answer if it wasn't about onload but only about onclick?

Comment: The answer to that would be in the form of a comment that asked `"What are you trying to achieve or avoid? Is this for a particular situation or are you wondering in general?"` Fortunately, the `onload` being part of the question just made it trivial to answer. Without a clear purpose for the question, it isn't really possible for me to be certain that any given answer would be satisfactory. Yes, I know - that was probably not the kind of answer you'd expect or prefer. As I said earlier, I find it an odd question, one which without any context seems unreasonable to answer definitively..